# Solve a system of parametric equations

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have a system of parametric equations (with a total number of 8). I tried to solve this system by using `Solve`. I have not received an answer after about 4 hours!

Is there a way to solve this equation system in a reasonable time?

```
bc1 = Subscript[C, 5] + (
   2 Subscript[B, 
    s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) (Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 2] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) + (Sqrt[A] Subscript[
          B, ges] (Subscript[C, 1] + Subscript[C, 3] + Subscript[C, 
            4]) + (Subscript[C, 1] - Subscript[C, 3] - Subscript[C, 
            4]) Subscript[p, 1]) Subscript[p, 2]))/(Sqrt[A] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 2]);

bc2 = 1/2 (-((2 q)/Subscript[NF, o]) + 1/(Sqrt[A] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 2])
       4 Subscript[B, 
       s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, 
         u]) ((Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 
            1]) (A Subscript[B, ges] Subscript[C, 2] - 
            Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 2] Subscript[p, 1] + 
            Subscript[C, 1] Subscript[p, 2]) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\) + (Subscript[C, 3] + 
            Subscript[C, 4]) (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p,
             1]) Subscript[p, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)));

bc3 = (-A^(3/2) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) (A^(
         3/2) (Subscript[C, 7] - Subscript[C, 8]) Subscript[p, 2] + 
        Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, 
         s] (-Subscript[C, 7] + Subscript[C, 8]) Subscript[p, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\) + 2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
           Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
     2 Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
        Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[p, 
      2] ((Subscript[C, 3] + Subscript[C, 4]) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) + Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))) + 
     Subscript[p, 
      1] (A Subscript[C, 7] Subscript[p, 1] Subscript[p, 
         2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
        A Subscript[C, 8] Subscript[p, 1] Subscript[p, 
         2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
           Subscript[B, u]) (Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 2] Subscript[p, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
           Subscript[p, 
            2] ((Subscript[C, 3] + Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                 Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) + Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (-A + Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))))))/(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[
     Subscript[B, s]] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 
     2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)));

bc4 = Subscript[C, 5] + L Subscript[C, 6] + 
   1/2 (-((L^2 q)/Subscript[NF, o]) + (
      4 E^(-L Subscript[p, 3]) Subscript[B, 
       s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 1])/(
      Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1])) + (
      4 E^(-L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[B, 
       s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 3])/(
      Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) + (
      4 E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[B, 
       s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 4])/(
      A Subscript[B, ges] + Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 1]) + (
      4 E^(L Subscript[p, 3]) Subscript[B, 
       s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2])/
      Subscript[p, 2]);

bc5 = 1/2 (-((2 q)/Subscript[NF, o]) + (
     4 E^(-L Subscript[p, 3]) Subscript[B, 
      s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))/(
     Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1])) + (
     4 E^(L Subscript[p, 3]) Subscript[B, 
      s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))/Subscript[p, 2] + (
     4 E^(-L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[B, 
      s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 3] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))/(
     Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) + (
     4 E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[B, 
      s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 4] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))/(
     A Subscript[B, ges] + Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 1]));

bc6 = (E^(-L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[p, 3] + 
        Subscript[p, 4])) (-A^(3/2) E^(
        L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) (2 E^(
           L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[p, 3])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
             Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) + 
          Sqrt[A] (Subscript[C, 7] - 
             E^((2 Sqrt[A] L)/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]]) Subscript[C, 
              8]) Subscript[p, 2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
       2 Sqrt[A] E^((Sqrt[A] L)/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]]) Subscript[B, 
        ges] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
          Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[p, 
        2] (E^(L Subscript[p, 
            3]) (Subscript[C, 3] + 
             E^(2 L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
             Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) + 
          E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))) + 
       Subscript[p, 
        1] (A E^(
           L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) (Subscript[C, 7] - 
             E^((2 Sqrt[A] L)/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]]) Subscript[C, 
              8]) Subscript[p, 1] Subscript[p, 2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
          2 E^(L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[p, 3])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
             Subscript[B, 
             u]) (Sqrt[A] E^(L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4]))
               Subscript[C, 2] Subscript[p, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
             Subscript[p, 
              2] ((Subscript[C, 3] + 
                   E^(2 L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                   Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) - 
                E^(L (-Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) Subscript[
                 C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)))))))/(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[
     Subscript[B, s]] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 
     2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)));

bc7 = -(1/
     2) (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, 
      u]) (-((4 Subscript[B, 
        s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\))/(
       Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1]))) + (
      4 Subscript[B, s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[
       C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\))/Subscript[p, 2] - (
      4 Subscript[B, s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[
       C, 3] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(3\)]\))/(
      Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) + (
      4 Subscript[B, s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[
       C, 4] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(3\)]\))/(
      A Subscript[B, ges] + Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 1])) + 
   A (Subscript[C, 7] + Subscript[C, 8] - (2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
           Subscript[B, u]) (A^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
           A Subscript[B, ges] Subscript[p, 
            2] ((Subscript[C, 3] - Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                 Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(3\)]\) + Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))) - 
           Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 
            1] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 2] Subscript[p, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
              Subscript[p, 
               2] (-(Subscript[C, 3] - Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                    Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(3\)]\) + Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))))))/(A (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 
         2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))));

bc8 = -(1/2) Subscript[B, 
    ges] (-((2 q)/Subscript[NF, o]) + (
      4 E^(-((L Subscript[p, 3])/2)) Subscript[B, 
       s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))/(
      Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1])) + (
      4 E^((L Subscript[p, 3])/2) Subscript[B, 
       s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))/Subscript[p, 2] + (
      4 E^(-((L Subscript[p, 4])/2)) Subscript[B, 
       s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 3] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))/(
      Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) + (
      4 E^((L Subscript[p, 4])/2) Subscript[B, 
       s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 4] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))/(
      A Subscript[B, ges] + 
       Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 1])) + (E^(-(1/2)
         L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[p, 3] + 
         Subscript[p, 4])) Sqrt[Subscript[B, 
      s]] (-A^(3/2) E^(1/2 L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) (2 E^(
            1/2 L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[p, 3])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
              Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) + 
           Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 7] Subscript[p, 
            2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) - 
           Sqrt[A] E^((Sqrt[A] L)/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]]) Subscript[C, 
            8] Subscript[p, 2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
        2 Sqrt[A] E^((Sqrt[A] L)/(2 Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]])) Subscript[
         B, ges] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
           Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[p, 
         2] (E^((L Subscript[p, 3])/
            2) (Subscript[C, 3] + 
              E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
              Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) + 
           E^((L Subscript[p, 4])/2) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))) + 
        Subscript[p, 
         1] (A E^(1/2 L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4]))
             Subscript[C, 7] Subscript[p, 1] Subscript[p, 
            2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
           A E^(1/2 L ((2 Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[
               p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) Subscript[C, 8] Subscript[p, 
            1] Subscript[p, 2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
           2 E^((Sqrt[A] L)/(2 Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
              Subscript[B, 
              u]) (Sqrt[A] E^(
               L Subscript[p, 3] + (L Subscript[p, 4])/2) Subscript[C,
                2] Subscript[p, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
              Subscript[p, 
               2] (E^((L Subscript[p, 3])/
                  2) (Subscript[C, 3] + 
                    E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                    Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) - 
                 E^((L Subscript[p, 4])/2) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)))))))/(Sqrt[A] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 
      2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)));

rc8 =  1/8 (2 L^2 q + 
     4 Subscript[NF, 
      o] (-2 Subscript[C, 5] - L Subscript[C, 6] - (
        4 E^(-((L Subscript[p, 3])/2)) Subscript[B, 
         s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 1])/(
        Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1])) - (
        4 E^(-((L Subscript[p, 4])/2)) Subscript[B, 
         s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) (Subscript[C, 3] + 
           E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]))/(
        Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) - (
        4 E^((L Subscript[p, 3])/2) Subscript[B, 
         s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2])/
        Subscript[p, 2]));

Solve[{bc1 == 0, bc2 == 0, bc3 == 0, bc4 == 0, bc5 == 0, bc6 == 0, 
  bc7 == q*L/2, bc8 == rc8}, {Subscript[C, 1], Subscript[C, 2], 
  Subscript[C, 3], Subscript[C, 4], Subscript[C, 5], Subscript[C, 6], 
  Subscript[C, 7], Subscript[C, 8] }]
```

Comment: copy your code and paste it into your question

Comment: The code is very long!

Comment: Is it possible to post the notebookk file here?

Comment: sorry for delay, first of all one need to avoid of using `Subscript` and `C` in the name of variables, use better x[y] instead of Subscript[x,y] and c[i] instead of C[i] becouse C is reserved symbol

Comment: to transform your equations to the wright form apply this code to each of them `/. {Subscript[C, i_] -> c[i], Subscript[A_, B_] -> A[B] }`

Comment: I uploaded the solution here https://yadi.sk/d/ugQVloNUegzMN

Comment: Thank you for your post. As expected the result is too long. In your attached file is just a compact solution for c[1] visible. How quickly did you get the result? I tried to generate the whole output for c[1]-c[8] and recieved no results after waiting for an hour!

Comment: I think there is no need to see the whole output in the text form, you may try to assign the solution to variable like this `sol=Solve[...]` and work then with `sol`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Beware, traveler: Much code ahead!

So, let's go:

`Subscript` is not a symbol for *Mathematica* (well, `Subscript` is, obviously, but its combination with arguments, i.e. `Subscript[...]` is not), which leads to surprising behavior sometimes. You can make symbols from such constructs with the `Notation` package however, if you really require that:

```
Needs["Notation`"];
sym[expr_]:=Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[ToBoxes[expr]]]
```

and make a symbol of `Subscript[x,y]` like so: `sym[Subscript[x,y]]`. Further information is found in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html).

If you do *not* want to deal with that, read on.

I took your equations and replaced the subscripts with the following construct (inspect the last four lines):

```
{bc1, bc2, bc3, bc4, bc5, bc6, bc7, bc8, rc8} = {Subscript[C, 5] + (
         2 Subscript[B, 
        s] (Subscript[B, o] + 
         Subscript[B, u]) (Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 2] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) + (Sqrt[A] Subscript[
                        B, 
              ges] (Subscript[C, 1] + Subscript[C, 3] + Subscript[C, 
                            4]) + (Subscript[C, 1] - 
               Subscript[C, 3] - Subscript[C, 
                            4]) Subscript[p, 1]) Subscript[p, 
           2]))/(Sqrt[A] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 2]),
   1/2 (-((2 q)/Subscript[NF, o]) + 1/(Sqrt[A] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 2])
              4 Subscript[B, 
               s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, 
                   u]) ((Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 
                         1]) (A Subscript[B, ges] Subscript[C, 2] - 
                        Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 2] Subscript[p, 1] + 
                        Subscript[C, 1] Subscript[p, 2]) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\) + (Subscript[C, 3] + 
                        Subscript[C, 4]) (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - 
            Subscript[p,
                          1]) Subscript[p, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))),
   (-A^(3/2) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) (A^(
                     3/2) (Subscript[C, 7] - 
            Subscript[C, 8]) Subscript[p, 2] + 
                 Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, 
                    s] (-Subscript[C, 7] + Subscript[C, 8]) Subscript[
           p, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\) + 2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
                       Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
           2 Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
                 Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[p, 
        2] ((Subscript[C, 3] + Subscript[C, 4]) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) + Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))) + 
           Subscript[p, 
              1] (A Subscript[C, 7] Subscript[p, 1] Subscript[p, 
                    2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
                 A Subscript[C, 8] Subscript[p, 1] Subscript[p, 
                    2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
            Subscript[B, u]) (Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 2] Subscript[p, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
                       Subscript[p, 
                          2] ((Subscript[C, 3] + Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                                   Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) + Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (-A + Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))))))/(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[
            Subscript[B, s]] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 
            2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))), 
   Subscript[C, 5] + L Subscript[C, 6] + 
       1/2 (-((L^2 q)/Subscript[NF, o]) + (
               4 E^(-L Subscript[p, 3]) Subscript[B, 
                  s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 
           1])/(
         Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1])) + (
               4 E^(-L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[B, 
                  s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 
           3])/(
         Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) + (
               4 E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[B, 
                  s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 
           4])/(
               A Subscript[B, ges] + Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 1]) + (
               4 E^(L Subscript[p, 3]) Subscript[B, 
                  s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 
           2])/
              Subscript[p, 2]), 1/2 (-((2 q)/Subscript[NF, o]) + (
             4 E^(-L Subscript[p, 3]) Subscript[B, 
                s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))/(
             Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1])) + (
             4 E^(L Subscript[p, 3]) Subscript[B, 
                s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))/Subscript[p, 2] + (
             4 E^(-L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[B, 
                s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 3] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))/(
             Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) + (
             4 E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[B, 
                s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 4] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))/(
        A Subscript[B, ges] + 
         Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 
           1])), (E^(-L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + 
           Subscript[p, 3] + 
                   Subscript[p, 4])) (-A^(3/2) E^(
                   L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) (2 E^(
              L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[p, 3])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
                           Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) + 
                     Sqrt[A] (Subscript[C, 7] - 
              E^((2 Sqrt[A] L)/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]]) Subscript[C, 
                              8]) Subscript[p, 2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
        2 Sqrt[A] E^((Sqrt[A] L)/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]]) Subscript[B, 
                  ges] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
                     Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[p, 
                  2] (E^(L Subscript[p, 
                            3]) (Subscript[C, 3] + 
              E^(2 L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                           Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) + 
                     E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))) + 
               Subscript[p, 
                  1] (A E^(
              L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) (Subscript[C, 
               7] - 
              E^((2 Sqrt[A] L)/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]]) Subscript[C, 
                              8]) Subscript[p, 1] Subscript[p, 
             2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
           2 E^(L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[p, 3])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
                           Subscript[B, 
               u]) (Sqrt[A] E^(L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4]))
                              Subscript[C, 2] Subscript[p, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
                           Subscript[p, 
                              2] ((Subscript[C, 3] + 
                    E^(2 L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                                       Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) - 
                 E^(L (-Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) Subscript[
                                    C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)))))))/(Sqrt[A] Sqrt[
            Subscript[B, s]] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 
            2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))), -(1/
             2) (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, 
              u]) (-((4 Subscript[B, 
                     s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[
             C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\))/(
           Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1]))) + (
         4 Subscript[B, 
           s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[
                  C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\))/Subscript[p, 2] - (
         4 Subscript[B, 
           s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[
                  C, 3] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(3\)]\))/(
         Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) + (
         4 Subscript[B, 
           s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[
                  C, 4] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(3\)]\))/(
               A Subscript[B, ges] + Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 1])) + 
       A (Subscript[C, 7] + Subscript[C, 8] - (2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
                       Subscript[B, u]) (A^2 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
                       A Subscript[B, ges] Subscript[p, 
                          2] ((Subscript[C, 3] - Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                                   Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(3\)]\) + Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))) - 
                       Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 
                          1] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 2] Subscript[p, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
                             Subscript[p, 
                 2] (-(Subscript[C, 3] - Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                                        Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(3\)]\) + Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(3\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))))))/(A (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 
                    2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)))), -(1/2) Subscript[B, 
          ges] (-((2 q)/Subscript[NF, o]) + (
               4 E^(-((L Subscript[p, 3])/2)) Subscript[B, 
                  s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 
           1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))/(
         Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1])) + (
               4 E^((L Subscript[p, 3])/2) Subscript[B, 
                  s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 
           2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))/Subscript[p, 2] + (
               4 E^(-((L Subscript[p, 4])/2)) Subscript[B, 
                  s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 
           3] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))/(
         Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) + (
               4 E^((L Subscript[p, 4])/2) Subscript[B, 
                  s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 
           4] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))/(
               A Subscript[B, ges] + 
                 Sqrt[A] Subscript[p, 1])) + (E^(-(1/2)
          L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[p, 3] + 
                     Subscript[p, 4])) Sqrt[Subscript[B, 
         s]] (-A^(3/2) E^(1/2 L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) (2 E^(
               1/2 L (Sqrt[A]/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + 
                  Subscript[p, 3])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
                             Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) + 
                       Sqrt[A] Subscript[C, 7] Subscript[p, 
                          2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) - 
            Sqrt[A] E^((Sqrt[A] L)/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]]) Subscript[C, 
                          8] Subscript[p, 2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\))) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
         2 Sqrt[A] E^((Sqrt[A] L)/(2 Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]])) Subscript[
                    B, ges] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
                       Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[p, 
                    2] (E^((L Subscript[p, 3])/
                            2) (Subscript[C, 3] + 
               E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                             Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) + 
                       E^((L Subscript[p, 4])/2) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))) + 
                 Subscript[p, 
                    1] (A E^(1/2 L (Subscript[p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4]))
                          Subscript[C, 7] Subscript[p, 1] Subscript[p, 
                          2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) - 
            A E^(1/2 L ((2 Sqrt[A])/Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]] + Subscript[
                                  p, 3] + Subscript[p, 4])) Subscript[
              C, 8] Subscript[p, 
                          1] Subscript[p, 2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
                       2 E^((Sqrt[A] L)/(2 Sqrt[Subscript[B, s]])) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(s\), \(5/2\)]\) (Subscript[B, o] + 
                             Subscript[B, 
                              u]) (Sqrt[A] E^(
                  L Subscript[p, 3] + (L Subscript[p, 4])/
                    2) Subscript[C,
                                 2] Subscript[p, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)) + 
                             Subscript[p, 
                                2] (E^((L Subscript[p, 3])/
                                      2) (Subscript[C, 3] + 
                    E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]) (A - 
                                        Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(4\)]\) - 
                  E^((L Subscript[p, 4])/2) Subscript[C, 1] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(4\)]\) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\)))))))/(Sqrt[A] (A 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(B\), \(ges\), \(2\)]\) - 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\), \(2\)]\)) Subscript[p, 
              2] (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(3\), \(2\)]\)) (A - Subscript[B, s] 
\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(p\), \(4\), \(2\)]\))), 1/8 (2 L^2 q + 
           4 Subscript[NF, 
              o] (-2 Subscript[C, 5] - L Subscript[C, 6] - (
                   4 E^(-((L Subscript[p, 3])/2)) Subscript[B, 
             s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 1])/(
           Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] - Subscript[p, 1])) - (
                   4 E^(-((L Subscript[p, 4])/2)) Subscript[B, 
             s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) (Subscript[C, 3] + 
                         E^(L Subscript[p, 4]) Subscript[C, 4]))/(
           Sqrt[A] (Sqrt[A] Subscript[B, ges] + Subscript[p, 1])) - (
                   4 E^((L Subscript[p, 3])/2) Subscript[B, 
             s] (Subscript[B, o] + Subscript[B, u]) Subscript[C, 2])/
                  Subscript[p, 2]))}/.{
   Subscript[a_, b_] :> Symbol[ToString@a <> ToString@b],
   SubsuperscriptBox[a_, b_,  c_] :> Power[Symbol[ToString@a <> ToString@b], c]
}
```

Now, we solve for

```
Solve[{bc1 == 0, bc2 == 0, bc3 == 0, bc4 == 0, bc5 == 0, bc6 == 0,
  bc7 == q*L/2, bc8 == rc8}, {C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8}]
```

and get a result pretty fast, i.e. in approximately 40s (a *large* one, however, which I will **not** reproduce here, since it is >800 kB…).

> ## Update
>
> You will find a notebook including the result [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ji5epayyva9u13a/mathematica.stackexchange.com.74117.nb?dl=0).
>   Or, should you want to try the approach mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74198), use the following image (save the image to your machine first!):

[image: encoded notebook]

> (try `seDecode@"<the downloaded PNG filename here>";`).

Comment: @alisha: I will compress the results, place them somewhere online and put links here this evening.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: @alisha: Done (see update above).

Comment: I can not follow your compressed result. 

It seems like: "LUB5UhWXQeWZtHc1ijxp2elxNSq7S5EhCkgKwIZIKdAxL6Yq3mQ3gGiCMXiiIOGsZouze/\
NbEd3ypBOd2EScmDy..."

Decoding your generated PNG file results in the same "compressed result". It would be very helpful if you could send the original notebook or result without compressing them. Thanks.

Comment: @alisha: Use `Uncompress[]`.