# HOWTO encode/decode large chunks of Mathematica code/results e.g. for posting on sites?

Tags: image, compression

At times, we as questioners would like to post huge *Mathematica*-expressions to websites (e.g. mathematica.stackexchange.com), or have an easy way to get such code from a site. Above a certain size, `Compress` yields lengthy strings, which are tedious to handle for both questioners and answerers.

Zipping might come to the rescue, however, more often than not, posting arbitrary attachments (e.g. *Mathematica*-notebooks or ZIP-files) is not allowed, while the full version of the expression or its `Compress`ed variant is too cumbersome to use.

In many cases and on most sites, images *are* allowed, but:

**How to effectively encode *Mathematica* expressions as images to be able to post them (and decode them afterwards)?**

Comment: A couple of years ago I posted [this idea](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/632/57) on Meta, which was extended in cooperation with belisarius (see same page). it's basically what you posted as a self-answer here.

Comment: Hmm. My intention was different, and the code is much simpler, but yes, there is some similarity in the idea.

Comment: "code simpler" . Did you see the full page? The code belisarius and I ended up at is encoding and decoding each in a single line of code each. Can't get much simpler than that.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: You are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quite handy approach of encoding *Mathematica*-expressions, even complete notebooks, as grayscaled images, which can be posted as PNG-files (and decoded afterwards).

Code for encoding and decoding is as follows:

```
(* general encoding to grayscale data *)
seEncode[expr_] := 
  Block[{cc = ToCharacterCode[Compress[expr]], olen, a}, 
   olen = Length@cc; a = Ceiling@Sqrt@olen;
   Image[Partition[PadRight[cc, a^2], a], "Byte"]];
(* encode to PNG file directly *)
seEncode[path_String, expr_] := Export[path, seEncode@expr, "PNG"];
(* encode current notebook *)
seEncodeNotebook[] := seEncode@NotebookGet@EvaluationNotebook[];
(* encode current notebook to PNG file directly *)
seEncodeNotebook[path_String] := 
  seEncode[path, NotebookGet@EvaluationNotebook[]];
(* decode an image *)
seDecode[img_Image] := 
  With[{dec = 
     Uncompress@FromCharacterCode@Flatten[ImageData[img, "Byte"]]}, 
   If[Head[dec] === Notebook, (NotebookPut@dec;), dec]];
(* decode from image file directly *)
seDecode[path_String] := seDecode@Import@path;
```

## Usage

1. Encoding:

   - Call `seEncode` on the expression you want to share. If you specify a filename, a PNG file will be created directly.
   - Call `seEncodeNotebook` to encode the current notebook.
2. Decoding:
   Call `seDecode` by saving or copy-pasting the (unscaled!) image from the site, or by giving a filename.
   This will reproduce the original expression (or notebook).

No tedious uploading on other (code-sharing, file-hosting, …) sites anymore!

Complete notebooks can be encoded by:

```
seEncodeNotebook@"<some path you choose>";
```

Example of output (a notebook containing only the code given above):

[image: Example encoded notebook containing the functions mentioned.]

and decoded accordingly using (after having saved the posted image to disk first for safety):

```
seDecode@"<path to the downloaded image file>";
```

**I hope, that this might be of some use to you all!**

Comment: There is no need for the decoding parameter - any characters added at the end of the compressed string will be ignored by `Uncompress`

Comment: I would also suggest using `Hold` or `Defer` as the second argument in `Uncompress`, for safety. Consider `seEncode@Unevaluated@Unevaluated@Print["oops"]` but with something nasty in place of the print.

Comment: @SimonWoods: I fixed the superfluous parameter and added some more convenience to the functions.