# How to use a picture to store some data

Tags: image-processing, data, data-structures

As we know.The values of the types is "Real" defaultly in `Mathematica`.In the `Image` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Image.en.html)'s detail we can see

> Image[data] is equivalent to Image[data,"Real"].

I have a thinking to use a picture to store some data.You know we can upload a picture very conveniently in $Stack\;Exchange$,but the data not.Like [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110327/interpolating-a-smooth-closed-surface-to-a-non-uniform-data-set-listsurfaceplot).Wen can set a link of dropbox for a large data-set.It very discommodiousness to a Chinese or other national user.So I have a try like follow:

```
SeedRandom[331]
data1 = RandomReal[{200, 300}, {5, 2}]
dataPic = Image[data1];
ImageData[dataPic]
```

> {{251.216, 212.714}, {230.544, 236.108}, {258.992, 267.498}, {245.38, 
>     299.614}, {291.842, 220.589}}
>
> {{251.216, 212.714}, {230.544, 236.108}, {258.992, 267.498}, {245.38, 
>     299.614}, {291.842, 220.589}}

We can get a data same to original data(data1).But when I try to `Export` the pictrue(Just we can export it then we can upload it to $Stack\;Exchange$)

```
Export["test2.jpg", dataPic];
Import["test2.jpg", "RawData"]
```

> {{255, 255}, {255, 255}, {255, 255}, {255, 255}, {255, 255}, {255,
>   255}, {255, 255}, {255, 255}, {255, 255}, {255, 255}}

We get a cliped data.So my wish that use pic to store data can be realize?

Comment: [Is there a way to facilitate the copy&paste process for code samples? (meta)](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/626/is-there-a-way-to-facilitate-the-copypaste-process-for-code-samples/632#632) and [HOWTO encode/decode large chunks of Mathematica code/results e.g. for posting on sites?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74198/howto-encode-decode-large-chunks-of-mathematica-code-results-e-g-for-posting-on)

Comment: This is what halirutan did to support notebook uploading for the [SE Tools](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1521/new-se-tools-formerly-known-as-se-uploader) palette.

Comment: See also this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13170/193

Comment: @Szabolcs Good links.

Comment: @C.E. Thanks your suggestion.

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Amazing....

Comment: @Szabolcs Could you give a explaination that `picLink= "http://i.stack.imgur.com/79TZu.gif";` can save two picture.And what's the meaning of `ImageData[importImage, "Byte"][[All, All, 1]]`?